# Why is the first part of equation i.e $v_0(t_f-t_0)$ not considered while plugging real life problem to it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, distance

[image]

Why is the speed*time stuff is not present while we look for the distance?
[image]

I got it from this (physics for dummies)

Comment: Because $v_0= 0\,?$ How could we know without knowing completely the question o.O

Comment: i have added the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 68 the paragraph headed *Calculating displacement given a time and acceleration* includes the text:

> Assume that you’re on your traditional weekend physics data-gathering expedition. Walking around with your clipboard and white lab coat, you happen upon a football game. Very interesting, you think. In a certain situation, you observe that the football, **although it starts from rest**, has three players subjecting forces on it, as you see in Figure 5-4.

The football starts from rest so $v_0 = 0$.

Comment: Can i rely on this book for starting with physics?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP: I don't know the book so I can't comment. I'm sure the book is reliable - whether it suits the way you like to learn is a matter for you to decide.